# Connecting DigitalOcean Managed MongoDB to Laravel (connection error calling ismaster)

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I'm attempting to set up Laravel with the Managed MongoDB provided by DigitalOcean, though for some reason the database is not connecting.

I've hit a wall and I think it's something to do with authSource, but can't replicate it via cli otherwise...

**.env file**

```
MONGO_DSN="mongodb+srv://username:password@digitaloceanhostname/databasename?authSource=admin"
MONGO_DATABASE="databasename"
MONGO_USER="username"
MONGO_PASSWORD="password"
MONGO_TLS=true 
MONGO_TLS_CERT="./mongo-db-cert.crt"
```

**config/database.php**

```
'connectionmethod' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'dsn' => env('MONGO_DSN'),
    'database' => env('MONGO_DATABASE', ''),
    'username' => env('MONGO_USER', ''),
    'password' => env('MONGO_PASSWORD', ''),
    'options'  => [
        'tls' => (bool) env('MONGO_TLS', false),
        'tlsCAFile' => env('MONGO_TLS_CERT', null),
        'authSource' => 'admin',
        'db' => 'admin',
        'database' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

The above causes the following error:

```
ERROR: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection error calling ismaster on 'digitaloceanhostname'
(MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\ConnectionTimeoutException(code: 13053): No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection error calling ismaster on 'digitaloceanhostname:27017']
```

However, when using the CLI to call ismaster, it works:

```
# mongo "mongodb+srv://MONGO_USER:MONGO_PASSWORD@digitaloceanhostname/MONGO_DATABASE?authSource=admin" --eval 'printjson(db.runCommand({"isMaster": 1}))' --ssl --sslCAFile ./mongo-db-cert.crt
```

Running it without the ?authSource=admin causes an authentication error, which is making me think the connection error from laravel is the same thing.

Environment:

```
# mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8

# apt list --installed | grep php | grep mongo
php7.4-mongodb/focal,now 1.9.0+1.7.5-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]

# php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.8.38
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but after looking at this all day any input is appreciated!

Comment: Hope you fixed this!

Comment: Did you check if outbound port 27017 is open from firewall? As your configuration looks pretty standard, the issue could be your firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Someone found a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to provide the FULL PATH to the certificate.